# PDF extraction issue with apache PDFBox 1.3.1

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am facing some issue while extracting data from PDF using apache PDFBox.
With PDFBox version 1.1, i was able to extract the data properly. But the same code is giving different output with version 1.3.1. Only for few PDFs,
I am facing this issue.

### Code sample

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("sample.pdf"));
PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
stripper.setSortByPosition( true );
System.out.println(stripper.getText(document));
```

Here is the sample output:

> With Version 1.1 : Account Number
>   xxxxx xxxxxx-xx-x .....
>
> With version 1.3.1: SCHDoe
>   SISInrPnnvuttccraareillreuucfczeX
>   dde,Pt reeF Hr rusdeDiIBc N dsDVeOe
>   I:PiiTgdtlaYieutais Bll  sXPuwF rn ew
>   df ew l er .rdceo dS
>   mwecritvhaiscte.cso 0 m 2  / 1 2 -
>   0431/01-1649-9105040.99 MURTgs Ac Bw
>   TAoiucllttciaonol g PuA Danmyta
>   otNeuunmt Dbueer 00$0T
>   P9122a5/0/g3117e198. /4/211 17 11o6f0
>   3498-01-6 THITTTPTNoFHHoDC ttEE HDaaDE
>   lliiAAP  ggVXAM-hiTRtTFda A Tueo .....

Anybody has any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend that you try PDFBox 1.5.0 from [here](http://pdfbox.apache.org/download.html) - a lot of text extraction issues have been [fixed](http://www.apache.org/dist/pdfbox/1.5.0/RELEASE-NOTES.txt) in this release.